# Json schema validation if/then ignored

Tags: json-schema-validator

I am using the schema in here: https://jsonschema.dev/s/5iht5 in my mac. But the validator doesn't seem to understand if.

```
warning: the following keywords are unknown and will be ignored: [if, then]
  level: "warning"
  schema: {"loadingURI":"#","pointer":"/definitions/legal/allOf/0"}
  domain: "syntax"
  ignored: ["if","then"]
```

This does not work in MAC / AL2 OS.

The expected outcome of validator is I want the required field to be applicable only when the value of the first attribute is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was using an older [validator](https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-schema-validator) that supports only until `draft-04`.

I am using `everit-org` [json-schema](https://github.com/everit-org/json-schema) now no longer see the warning.